# dual norm for $\|x\| \leq C$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

The dual of a norm $\|\cdot \|$ is defined as:

$$|\|z\|| = \sup \{ z^Tx \text{ } | \text{ } \|x\| \le 1\}$$

Consider $\sup \{ z^Tx \text{ } | \text{ } \|x\| \le C\}$.

Why is this equal to: $C \sup \{ z^Tx \text{ } | \text{ } \|x\| \le 1\}$

Comment: Linearity of scalar product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any vector $x$ such that $\|x\| \leq C$ may be written as $x = Cy$ with  $\|y\| \leq 1$ (by dividing $x$ by $C$).

$$\sup \{ z^Tx \text{ } | \text{ } \|x\| \le C\} =
\sup \{ z^T(Cy) \text{ } | \text{ } \|Cy\| \le C\} =
\sup \{ z^T(Cy) \text{ } | \text{ } \|y\| \le 1\} =
C \sup \{ z^Ty \text{ } | \text{ } \|y\| \le 1\}.
$$